# Would Javascript “private” variable nameswith underscore in module pattern conflict with underscore.js

Tags: javascript

I am using Crockford Module pattern and am using underscores to denote “private” variables.

My work may be used in an html page that uses underscore.js, which I understand uses an underscore to denote itself, much like $ indicate jQuery. My question-
would my use of underscore screw things up, as it would be read as underscore libraray?

I know underscore usually uses _.stuff --- my variable name is of format
_varName. So would the dot prevent conflict?

Thanks!

Comment: tip: if you can, use lodash instead of underscore (unless you enjoy slower libraries with bugs and cross-browser inconsistencies).

Comment: When you are satisfied with an answer, you should click the check mark to indicate that you approved the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be ok.  Underscore only uses "_".  It doesn't use _myvarname, it only uses _.

The reason there is a . is because _ is an object as in `_ = {key1:value1, key2:value2, ...}` that contains the various functions (e.g. each) as the properties of the object _ : (e.g. _.each() ).

This is like jQuery using $, except jQuery's $ is a function.

So as long as none of your variables are called "_", by itself, you are fine.

There is also an option in underscore to use something else, like U, or another character, to hold the underscore object in case _ needs to be used elsewhere.  However, that would probably be unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks! I am new to Javascript, so I was unsure how to even test this scenario, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The Underscore `_` is a global variable, i.e. a property of the global object.

Your names are a) only prefixed with `_`, not equal to it b) properties of *your* own instances.

They can't collide with each other.

> So would the dot prevent conflict?

Yes. It syntactically separates them so that they do semantically mean absolutely different things.